# Using a variable with module functions

Tags: python, variables, module

How would I go about using a variable object to reference objects within a module or objects within a function within a module.

I am iterating through a keystring and would like to use a single character as a variable object to reference a dictionary within an imported module. I have also attempted to build a function within the module but to no luck.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
...
import cipher
KeyString = 'AbCd0123'
for keystringCharacter in KeyString: 
    ReferenceList = cipher.keystringCharacter
# keystringCharacter has a value of 'A' and cipher has an object (list) of 'A' which I need to reference.
```

How would I go about using a variable to reference an object within this imported module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm):

```
for letter in keyString:
    cipherVariables.append(getattr(cipher, letter))
```

The contents of `cipherVariables` would be something like this:

```
[cipher.A, cipher.b, cipher.C, ... cipher.3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` and a list comprehension:

```
reference_list = [ getattr(cipher, ksc) for ksc in KeyString ]
```